geolocation getCurrentPosition - is there ever a time when a location wouldn't be available in cache?
I'm reading the docs on getCurrentPosition. For the maximumAge option it states:

If set to Infinity the device must return a cached position regardless
of its age.
(my bolding)

The word 'must' in that sentence is what I'm curious about. Is there ever a time when there is no cached position to retrieve? If so, what is the behaviour? Does it go fetch or return an error or null value?

Yes, there can be instances where there is no cached position available.
If no cached position exists, the getCurrentPosition method will attempt to fetch a new location from the device. If it cannot retrieve the location (e.g., due to lack of signal or permissions), it will return an error, such as POSITION_UNAVAILABLE. It does not return null or a cached value if one is not available.
